# Django how to properly add validation error message in views

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add validation in my views but error message not showing in my template. I am getting this page if user enter wrong input:

[image]

views.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
if request.method == "POST":
        if comment_form.is_valid():
             
             if request.POST['name'] != username:
                raise forms.ValidationError('inc')
```

This code prevent submitting my forms until user input correct details which is great but why validation error message not showing in template?

Comment: Show us the template code and also the complete method in your views.py

Comment: I don't think I need to be add full code because problem happening for above code which I wrote.

Comment: Try form.add_error('Username mis-match') inside your if block. Reason why I wanted to see the method in views.py is to see how you return your template. And template code, to see how you show alert-{errors}.

Comment: @incrediblegiant  my views.py code is very long. here is google drive link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wk7mJcGFM-KdsJW24-QtqZS_Vfjmyp1h/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, I'd suggest using Class based views and form_valid methods. They are lot cleaner and DRYer. The piece of code you shared doesn't have the above chunk (raise forms.ValidationError). From whatever is shared, try returning your form like so {form:form} in your render statement along with template name. That way, your template will have access to form.errors